# Oracle SQL to change column type from varchar2(10) to char(10) while it contains data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

How to change column type from varchar2(10) to char(10) without losing existing data using oracle developer?

ALTER TABLE TBL_NAME
MODIFY (CRTE CHAR(10));

Will it impact existing data?

Comment: Why do you want to to this? The `CHAR` data type is pretty useless.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I gonna add an FK constraint on this column, reference table column type is char, so this should be changed.

Comment: `CHAR` can be really annoying. I'd rather change the other table's type from `CHAR` to `VARCHAR2`.

Comment: Yes, it will impact existing data. All values will be right-padded with space ` ` characters up to 10-

Answer (score 0):

It should not impact existing data.

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f8921c/1).

I would reconsider changing `varchar2` for `char`. Char will take up more space on HDD as `char` will always take N bytes. And if your strings are not execatly 10 characters, all of them `char` will be pain for searches.

Comment: Your assertion that there will be no impact is incorrect, and your demo of such is fatally flawed.  As you said, " Char will take up more space on HDD as char will always take N bytes".  Yes, and it will always take N bytes because it will right-pad with spaces.  So a VARCHAR2(10) column containing 'A', when converted to CHAR(10), will become 'A         '.  ('A' followed by 9 spaces).  And 'A'  !=  'A         '.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no reason to do this.  [As this "Ask Tom" answer](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:123212348063,), explains, the two are stored equivalently.

If you want to ensure that the value has exactly 10 characters, then use a `check` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE TBL_NAME ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK (LEN(CRTE) = 10);
```

The difference is padding the string in result sets, and that is often better handled on an ad-hoc basis.  Trailing spaces can be quite tricky to deal with.

If you really want to change the column type, you can use:

```
alter table t modify (  x char(10) );
```

This should be safe with existing data, because you are not reducing the length of the column.